# Opening Window/Showing UserControl in WPF MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I'm trying out MVVM with a simple project using WPF and I've got the grips on mostly how the pattern works and their intentions. However, one of my problem now is how navigation is done in MVVM. For example, when I have a navigation pane and I need to show a UserControl on the right-side of a window based on what item is clicked on the navigation pane. Or showing a new window.

How is this done in MVVM? I've browsed the internet but all implementations I see uses IoC containers. I want to implement the application without these frameworks as I want to understand how it works. Some have mentioned using controllers for navigation but I can't seem to find a simple and short example.

Basically, I need a short and simple example of how it navigation is done in WPF MVVM.

Comment: Perhaps you'd be interested in a simplified blog post I wrote on this subject back when I was facing the exact same problem as you? [Navigation with MVVM](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/12/18/navigation-with-mvvm-2/)

Comment: Hi Rachel, thanks for the link, very nice. May I ask if you have used this approach in large scale applications? Thanks.

Comment: I've mostly built small or mid-sized WPF applications. The one large one I was working on got cancelled about a year into development, however I used  a version of the same method there without any noticeable problems (I think I had Regions in the main screen there, and each region had it's own ViewModel controlling what was displayed).